# Perplexity comparision issue in SKlearn LDA vs Gensim LDA

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, lda, gensim

I applied lda with both sklearn and with gensim. Then i checked perplexity of the held-out data.

I am getting negetive values for perplexity of gensim and positive values of perpleixy for sklearn. How do i compare those values.

sklearn perplexity = 417185.466838

gensim perplexity = -9212485.38144

Comment: How did you obtain both perplexities ?

Comment: @MMF In sklearn :- lda.perplexity(doc_test) and in gensim :- ldamodel.bound(doc_test)

Answer (score 2):

In order to compare perplexities you need to convert gensim's perplexity using `np.exp(-1. * gensim_model.log_perplexity(train_corpus))`.

See [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/457) for a general comparison of Gensim and Sklearn LDA implementations.